# How to design constructor inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I love C# but just could'nt find a solution. This is obviously a simplification.

Suppose we have classes Animal, Dog, Cat, Furniture, Chair, TallDog.

Animals has a name. Furniture has a height.

BUT. A sudden TallDog appears. It has a name **and** a height.

What do you do to avoid the repeatition of height in TallDog and Furniture?

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(string name)
        : base(name)
    {

    }
}
class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name)
        : base(name)
    {

    }
}
abstract class Furniture
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public Furniture(int height)
    {
        Height = height;
    }
}
class Chair : Furniture
{
    public Chair(int height)
        : base(height)
    {

    }
}
class TallDog : Animal
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public TallDog(string name, int height)
        : base(name)
    {
        Height = height;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'd avoid the repetition of the *implementation*... but if you wanted to be able to (say) compare the height of any tall dog and any piece of furniture, you could make both `Furniture` and `TallDog` implement a common interface.

Comment: I don't think that being tall makes a dog a piece of furniture. ;)

Comment: @CharlesMager who is that comment directed at?

Comment: @AntP the question? It's just a bit of fun - though given inheritance represents an 'is a' relationship, it is also true. Jon Skeet's suggestion is how this should probably be solved.

Comment: public class Thing { public double Weight; public double Width; public double Height; public string Name; }  But don't get all hyped about inheritance.  It's often better to compose.  Height doesn't have to be a property, it can be one of many aspects of a thing...

Comment: Please treat `Furniture` as `Sizable`. @CharlesMager

Comment: @TheSilence so the best options it to have `TallDog : ISizable` and `Furniture : ISizable`.

Comment: The repetition of the implementation of the constructor is the problem here. @JonSkeet

Comment: This does not solve the problem. @AntP

Comment: @TheSilence you can't treat assignment of two class members of the same name in different classes as duplication. Firstly because it's practically impossible and secondly because then you'll couple all your implementations together in very bad ways. Just because they look the same doesn't mean they're the same thing. They're different properties on different classes - just do two assignments.

Comment: @TheSilence to be honest I would normally even do away with `Animal` and just have interfaces for your animal behaviours and have `Dog : IWhateverAnimalsDo` and duplicate those assignments too - this kind of inheritance is not normally a good road to travel. You are already bumping into its limitations (hence this question).

Comment: What do you do to avoid the repetition of height in TallDog and Furniture? Nothing. You spend your valuable time and effort solving problems that actually impact your line of business.

Comment: In most cases - there is no problem. Often many classes will have properties of the same name without any need for any kind of inheritance. In the particular case where you need to be able to interchangeably use the objects, interfaces or inheritance as appropriate, but just because a dog and furniture have heights doesn't mean they will actually be used interchangeably.

Comment: Change name of TallDog's property to one of acceptable synonyms. code will not be repeated. Does it solve your problem? If not, why?
I do not think that duplicating a code is a real problem. You can have a problem when you implement the same thing twice, no matter whether the code is identical or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep in mind that "good OO" is mainly about **behavior** of objects. Objects (and classes) exist to "map" some "concept out of reality" into the "model" that you make the base of your application.

Thus: you don't use *inheritance* to save a line of code here or there. You put the "B extends A" tag on B because that is the reasonable thing to do **guided** by your model.

Given that: your idea of making a *tall* dog a **furniture** is a very nice example for people using inheritance for the completely wrong reasons!

Thus: simply forget about this idea; and do as the comments suggest: create reasonable interfaces, and put those classes where they make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Factory Implementation utilizing generics and Interfaces to achieve your goal with only default constructors.

```
public interface INameable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IMeasurable
{
    int Height { get; set; }
}

abstract class Animal: INameable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Dog : Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }

abstract class Furniture: IMeasurable
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
class Chair : Furniture { }

class TallDog : Animal, IMeasurable
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public T NameableFactory<T>(string name)
    where T:INameable, new()
{
    return new T { Name = name };
}

public T MeasurableFactory<T>(int height)
    where T : IMeasurable, new()
{
    return new T { Height = height };
}

public T NameableMeasurableFactory<T>(string name, int height)
    where T : INameable, IMeasurable, new()
{
    return new T { Name = name , Height = height };
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestFactories()
{
    Cat ct = NameableFactory<Cat>("milo");
    Chair ch = MeasurableFactory<Chair>(5);
    TallDog td = NameableMeasurableFactory<TallDog>("Fido", 5);
}
```

Comment: This will technically mitigate the two lines of code the OP is hell-bent on deduplicating but I sure as hell wouldn't want to extend or maintain this implementation.

Comment: A factory method for every possible permutation of interfaces? And as soon as you want your implementations to differ, the whole thing falls to pieces.

Comment: How would you approach this problem?

Comment: With interfaces. Possibly the strategy pattern depending on shared implementations. By not trying to deduplicate simple constructor assignments at the cost of maintain ability and extensibility.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea.  Care to provide some code? I'll gladly remove this answer.